# how to insert data into table from stored proc, manual values together in a single insert statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Can anyone tell me how to insert a record in a table in the following case:

I have 2 tables:

```
create table #temp1(c4 int, c5 int,c3 int)
```

...and:

```
create table #temp2(c1 int, c2 int)
```

---

```
create procedure sptemp
as
begin
  select c1,c2 from #temp2
end
```

---

Now I want to insert records into #temp1 table using the procedure as:

```
insert into #temp1(c4,c5,c3)
```

In the above statement, first 2 values(c4,c5) should be from procedure(exec sptemp) and the third value will be using (ex: values(34)).

Please suggest me the way to implement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Sql Server 2005 you can exec a sp into a table var

```
DECLARE @TBL TABLE(
        C1 INT,
        C2 INT
)

INSERT INTO @TBL (C1, C2) EXEC sptemp

SELECT *, 34 FROM @TBL
```